# Iterating Over a List of Lists in Haskell?

Tags: loops, haskell, functional-programming, iteration

I'm having some difficulties understanding how to iterate through a list in Haskell. I've been trying to work with mapM but for some reason I keep on coming up with parsing errors. I know that this can be done recursively, but the code within the iteration/for loop is only a small part of the whole function so I wouldn't want to recursively call the function. So for example, if I have a list of lists like

```
[[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```

how would I go about first iterating through each list to see if the sum of values in each list is > 5 and then within each list, iterating through the individual values to check if there is an integer = 2 in the list (and return True in that case)?

Comment: You do not need anything like `mapM`, that is for monads (yes a list is a monad, but this is making things very complex). You can use `filter` here.

Comment: `all (\xs -> sum xs > 5 && 2 \`elem\` xs)`  I expect that you have learned almost nothing from this answer though.  How about you try implementing solutions manually (both using functions from `base` and your own primitive recursive functions) then come back with questions specific to those attempts?  You'd learn a lot faster that way.

Answer (score 2):

> how would I go about first iterating through each list to see if the sum of values in each list is > 5

Lets say your list is

```
l = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```

You can get the lists whose values sum up more than five, using `filter`. The first argument of `filter` is a function `(\xs -> sum xs > 5)`, that given a list `xs`, decides if the sum of its elements is bigger than 5

```
> filter (\xs -> sum xs > 5) l
[[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
```

> and then within each list, iterating through the individual values to check if there is an integer = 2 in the list

Same as before, you use filter, but now you check if number `2` is an element of each list `xs`

```
> filter (\xs -> 2 `elem` xs) l
[[0,1,2],[2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear to me exactly what you want to do, but here are some building blocks that may help:

1. Find which lists have a sum greater than 5:

   ```
   Prelude> filter ((>5) . sum) [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
   [[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
   ```
2. Find whether a list contains the number 2:

   ```
   Prelude> any (==2) [1,2,3]
   True
   Prelude> any (==2) [4,5,6]
   False
   ```
3. Combine the above, to give True / False for each list whose sum is greater than 5:

   ```
   Prelude> (map (any (==2)) . filter ((>5) . sum)) [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
   [True,False]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are iterative. I'm not sure what you want so the following creates a tuple of the sum greater than 5 of each list and the second item of the tuple weather any element of the list is 2. The check for elements equal to 2 is another short list comprehension.

```
[(a,[True|t<-b,t == 2])|b<-[[0,1,2],[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8]], a<-[sum b], a>5]
```

> [(14,[True]),(21,[])]